# How can I write a microcontroller for an RGB keyboard?

Tags: c++, keyboard, driver, microcontroller

I have a Modecom Volcano Hammer RGB keyboard, and I'd like to make a custom led controlling program. 
I'm a programmer, but my main languages are C#, PHP and JavaScript. Unfortunately, I'm not so experienced with hardware programming. 
How can I start? I read tons of pages, I made several google search, but I didn't find the answer. So I'd like to control my keyboard's LEDs, probably it's petty simple, but I don't know either the keywords. 
Yes, I know, I have to ask the manufacturer, but it's not an option, because they don't answer. 
So, any suggestions?

Comment: Sniff the usb communication to the keyboard and/or reverse engineer the driver.

Comment: are you not able to control the leds from the host isnt that the point?  this will not be a trivial task, attacking the driver is likely the best bet.   if there is a linux driver then that may give a lot more information and if running linux then that driver would obviously be easier to modify